# Parse table using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have some table

```
<table>
        <tr class="odd">
        <td class="ind gray">1</td>
        <td><b>acceding</b></td>
        <td class="transcr">[əksˈiːdɪŋ]</td>
        <td class="tran">присоединения</td>
      </tr>
<!-- .... -->
        <tr class="odd">
        <td class="ind gray">999</td>
        <td><b>related</b></td>
        <td class="transcr">[rɪlˈeɪːtɪd]</td>
        <td class="tran">родственный</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I want parse three "td" in one row. 
My code

```
Dictionary<string, Word> words = new Dictionary<string, Word>();
string text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);
for (int i = 0; i < doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").Count; i++)
{
     HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")[i];
     Word word = null;
     if (TryParseWord(node, out word))
     {
          try
          {
               if (!words.ContainsKey(word.eng))
               {
                    words.Add(word.eng, word);
               }
          }
          catch
          { continue; }
     } 
}
```

And function for parsing

```
private bool TryParseWord(HtmlNode node, out Word word)
{
    word = null;
    try
    {
        var eng = node.SelectNodes("//td")[1].InnerText;
        var trans = node.SelectNodes("//td")[2].InnerText;
        var rus = node.SelectNodes("//td")[3].InnerText;
        word = new Word();
        word.eng = eng;
        word.rus = rus;
        word.trans = trans;
        return true;

    }
    catch
    {
        word = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my method TryParseWord I have value only from first row.
How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Your current parsing code is **littered** with re-executions of queries you already have the results of. Fixing that would be a good start. Look closely everywhere you have quotes. Many of those places are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can get the values this way easily

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);

 var table = doc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants("tr")
            .Select(n => n.Elements("td").Select(e => e.InnerText).ToArray());
```

And usage:

```
foreach (var tr in table)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", tr[0], tr[1], tr[2], tr[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the XPath so that it doesn't match from the start again. Like this:

```
node.SelectNodes(".//td")[1]
```

The dot tells the XPath to only match from the current node.